# java.math.BigDecimal.scale() equivalent for double

Tags: java, apache-commons

I've got a matrix of values like the one below that I need to scale. I've been looking around for an inbuilt function if there is one that could do this for me. I haven't found one & so have ended up writing code to do the scaling using the below formula

```
scaledMatrix = (Matrix - MeanMatrix)/Standard Deviation
```

This code is a bit buggy & I'm working on correcting it. While I do that, I happened to bump on `java.math.BigDecimal.scale()` & did look up an equivalent for `double` as the matrix I have is `double` type numbers

If someone could please help me with details on

```
1) If there is an inbuilt function that accepts matrix of values & returns me the scaled matrix
2) `java.math.BigDecimal.scale()` equivalent for `double` type data
```

Any help would be much appreciated please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BigDecimal.scale()` method does not do what you seem to think it is doing. A `BigDecimal` value is stored as `a * 10^b` (where `^` denotes exponentiation). The `BigDecimal.scale()` method basically returns the `b` part of that.

I do not know of a similar method for `double` values, nor do I know of a method which performs the function you need. Since you put apache-commons in the tags, I suggest you look into Apache Commons's extensive statistical library.

Comment: Thank you Hoopje. This helps me in the sense that it clarifies that this method nor an equivalent method actually helps me with what I'm after which you've rightly sensed. I did look up the statistics library & can't find a function for this which is really strange.